# implementing python's 'if X in List' in C++

Tags: python, c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

We have an array object in C++, and a value. We want to control this value have in array or not have in array. How we can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little example using `std::find()`

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
 {
   std::array<int, 5> a1 { { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 } };

   std::cout << "8 is in a1 ? "
      << (a1.cend() != std::find(a1.cbegin(), a1.cend(), 8)) << std::endl;

   std::cout << "7 is in a1 ? "
      << (a1.cend() != std::find(a1.cbegin(), a1.cend(), 7)) << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Can work with every container that implement or support `begin()` and `end()` (or better, `cbegin()` and `cend()`)